# UIImageの幅を可変にしたい

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

カスタムセルの中に UIImage を配置し、画像が存在する場合は画像を表示し、画像が存在しない場合は画像を非表示にしたいです。

下記のように Constraint を IBOutlet で繋ぎ、調節しようとしたのですが、うまくいきません。
エラー内容としては、一番最後の行の`"cell.thumImageWidthConstraint.constant = 0.0"`で Exception が発生してしまい、

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

となってしまいます。

アドバイス頂けたらうれしいです。

[コード]

```
var cell : BingWebCustomCell! = nil
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WebCell") as! BingWebCustomCell               

if self.bingImageArray.isEmpty == false && self.bingImageArray.count > indexPath.row{
    let imageUrlStr: String? = self.bingImageArray[indexPath.row] as? String
    if imageUrlStr != ""{
       let imageUrl: NSURL? = NSURL(string: imageUrlStr!)
       cell.thumImage.kf_setImageWithURL(imageUrl!) //download image via "Kingfisher" library
       cell.thumImageWidthConstraint!.constant = 128.0
    }else{
       cell.thumImageWidthConstraint.constant = 0.0
    }
}else {
  cell.thumImageWidthConstraint.constant = 0.0
}
```

[環境]

- Xcode7.0.1
- Swift2.0
- El Capitan (ver10.11)
- Deployment Target iOS8.2

Comment: 直接の原因は`cell`か`thumImageWidthConstraint`のどちらかがnilですね。とりあえずどちらがnilなのか確かめてください。

Comment: コメントを頂いて、よーく見なおしてみたら、cellのidentifierが間違っていてnilになっていました。凡ミスで恥ずかしいです。アドバイスどうもありがとうございました。